# Svelte selection based master/detail not updating correctly

Tags: svelte

Bear with me, Svelte newbie question coming.

I have a selection based Master/Detail view like the following simplified version:

```
<script>
    let data = [{ x: 10},{ x: 20},{ x:30}]
    let selected = data[1];
</script>
<table>
    {#each data as row}
      <tr>
            <button class="{selected === row ? 'selected' : ''}"
                            on:click={() => selected = row}>Select</button>
             <td><input type="number" bind:value={row.x}/></td>
        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>

<br/><br/>
Detail: <input type="number" bind:value={selected.x}/>

<style>
    .selected { background-color: #ff3e00; color: white; }
</style>
```

This works correctly if you select different rows (the Detail updates with the selected row).
Unfortunately, however, the Detail does not update if the value of the selected item in the top list is changed.  Also, the list item value does not update if the Detail is changed.  A side note: If you change the list value, then select a different item and switch back, the Detail view does show the correct value.

To fix it, I switched to an index based selection:

```
<script>
    let data = [{ x: 10},{ x: 20},{ x:30}]
    let selectedIndex = 1;
    $: selected = data[selectedIndex];
</script>
<table>
    {#each data as row, i}
      <tr>
            <button class="{selectedIndex === i ? 'selected' : ''}"
                            on:click={() => selectedIndex = i}>Select</button>
             <td><input type="number" bind:value={row.x}/></td>
        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>

<br/><br/>
Detail: <input type="number" bind:value={selected.x}/>


<style>
    .selected { background-color: #ff3e00; color: white; }
</style>
```

What I can’t figure out is why the first version doesn’t work?  What magic am I missing?  Further, why did the second version fix it?  Both, to me, seem like they should behave the same.

I really like Svelte, but before I can invest heavily I need to know it truly does handle all reactive updating correctly.

Comment: The critical mindset shift (from React's approach) required to understand Svelte, is to construct a dependency graph in your mind when coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svelte does not know that `row.x` and `selected.x` might be referring to the same thing, which is why the first version of the code does not work as expected.

The second version only works because of this reactive statement:

```js
$: selected = data[selectedIndex];
```

Changes to `row.x` invalidate `data` and that causes the reactive statement to be reevaluated, thus updating `selected.x`. Changes to `selected.x` are propagated to `row.x` because `data` and `selectedIndex` are invalidated on change, since they are used in the reactive statement.

Essentially the reactive statement establishes the logical relationship between `selected` and `data` which would otherwise not be visible to the Svelte compiler.

Comment: Ahh…  I think I get it.  Svelte applies reactivity at the code level (being a compiler) and not at the object level.  I.e., it does not create a full dependency graph between object (or more correctly, their fields)—but instead compiles the Svelte input to Javascript that will invalidate pure JS objects based on the rules that can be inferred at compile time.

Comment: One more question/thought:  Is the index based approach the right way to do this?

Comment: @EricHewitt Yes it's the right way to go. This resonates with "single source of truth" principle. If you want a selection from a collection, you better use a declarative selector (the `$` statement in svelte) that keeps in-sync the relationship between the selection and collection. If you do it imperatively, it'll probably go out-of-sync at some point.

Comment: @EricHewitt: I agree with hackape; I tried to think of alternatives but just using an index like this is probably the way to go.